# Comparar elementos de dos listas en Haskell

Tags: haskell

He probado a comparar elementos pertenecientes a dos listas en **Haskell** y no termino de comprender el resultado obtenido.

Cito de [aprendehaskell.es](http://aprendehaskell.es/content/Empezando.html#una-introduccion-a-las-listas):

> Las listas pueden ser comparadas si los elementos que contienen pueden ser comparados. Cuando usamos <, <=, >, y >= para comparar listas, son comparadas en orden lexicográfico. Primero son comparadas las cabezas. Luego son comparados los segundos elementos y así sucesivamente.

Decidí probar en el compilador WinGHCI la siguiente comparación:

```
Prelude> [1,2,3] < [4,5,2]
```

El resultado obtenido fue: `True`

Lo que yo entendía de la cita, es que al ir comparando en orden lexicográfico, primero compara el 1 con el 4, y como 1<4, es true, después compara el 2 con el 5, y como 2<5 es true, pero, al comparar 3<2 debería salir `false`. De manera que el resultado que yo esperaba era false. Sin embargo, obtengo true.

La pregunta es, ¿Haskell solo compara el primer elemento y no compara el resto?, o ¿compara primero el primero, luego el segundo...? PERO ¿siempre se queda con el resultado del primero? lo cual sería absurdo, pues no tendría sentido realizar el resto de operaciones ya que el resultado no va a variar.

Gracias

Comment: El orden *lexicográfico* es el usado para ordenar las palabras en un diccionario. Se empieza por la primera letra, usando la segunda y siguientes cuando dos palabras empiezan igual. Del mismo modo que no necesitas comparar todas las letras de una palabra para saber entre qué palabras encaja, lo mismo pasa con las listas de haskell. Gracias a la *evaluación perezosa*, no necesita comparar todos los elementos si ya solo con los primeros puede llegar a deducir cuál es su orden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando dos listas se comparan por orden lexicográfico, **se comparan elemento a elemento hasta que alguno de ellos difiere**, o hasta que se acaban los elementos de alguna de las dos listas (en cuyo caso todos los elementos hasta el momento eran iguales y es más pequeña la lista con menos elementos). Esto no es una característica especial de Haskell, otros lenguajes como Python implementan el mismo criterio.

Por eso, en tu ejemplo `[1,2,3] < [4,5,2]` la primera lista es menor que la segunda, porque el primer elemento de la primera ya es menor que el primer elemento de la segunda. Si las listas fuesen `[4,5,2] < [4,5,1]`, como los dos primeros elementos de ambas listas son iguales, llegaría a compararse el `2` con el `1`, determinando que la primera lista es mayor que la segunda.

La comparación que tú esperas, donde todos los elementos deben ser mayores, menores, etc, puedes conseguirla por ejemplo, comparando los elementos con `zipWith`:

```
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

`zipWith` toma una función (en este caso `(<)`, `(>)`, `(<=)` o `(>=)`)  y dos listas, y combina las listas aplicando dicha función. Por ejemplo:

```
ghci> zipWith (<) [1,2,3] [4,5,2]
[True, True, False]
```

Finalmente, puedes utilizar la función `and :: Foldable t => t Bool -> Bool`
 para comprobar que todos los elementos de la lista son `True`, es decir, que todos los elementos satisfacen la relación de orden aplicada elemento a elemento.

```
ghci> and $ zipWith (<) [1,2,3] [4,5,2]
False
ghci> and $ zipWith (<) [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
True
ghci> and $ zipWith (>=) [1,2,6] [1,2,1]
True
```